# uploading large file custom plugin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am making custom plug in in which I am uploading csv file and updating the database . Problem is that the csv file is nearly 350MB and when I try to upload it on local-host it give me this error

```
[error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  POST Content-Length of 322904214 bytes exceeds the limit of 104857600 bytes
```

I am using simple form to upload file , is there any good way to do this so user can upload large amount of file

Comment: Even with higher upload limits, I suppose you'll have processing problems with this amount of data. Try to break the execution (or even the csv file) in smaller chunks.

Comment: What i was thinking to upload the file first and than do the processing i am also increasing the script time so it will not effect

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to increase some limits in your `php.ini` server configuration file.  Try this:

```
upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
```

Updating these two values would set your max upload size at 512mb.  The default is usually a lot lower.  Contact your hosting / server provider about changing php.ini - if you cannot change it you are probably out of luck.

On localhost the location of php.ini depends on what localhost stack you are using, but in WAMP you can access it by clicking the icon to open the WAMP menu, going to PHP and there is an option for php.ini.

Comment: Hi i did that and after updating php.ini file i restart the apache too but no help same error

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the right php.ini and restarting the server correctly?  If you got that identical error it would imply you are not, because at the very least, the "exceeds to limit of 104857600 bytes" (100mb) part of the error message should have increased to 512mb.

Comment: You can also try increasing `max_execution_time` in `php.ini` (the value is in seconds) to something long enough to accommodate the amount of time it may take to upload/process large files.

Comment: i tried that and again same error . I am doing changes on right php.ini file is there any way in wordpress that define the maximum file size ?